# Full list of symbols not supported in the cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, sound, cloud-deploy

I planned to use `AudioCapture[]` in a cloud notebook and just found out it’s not supported. There used to be a convenient “not in the cloud” icon in a symbols documentation page, but it’s gone now.

Answer (score 5):

Why not trying

```
EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "CloudSupportStatus" -> "NotSupported"]["Entities"]
```

It results in 236 symbols (for version 13.2).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a complete answer.**

In chrome on the mac using these versions:

```
In[2]:= $Version
Out[2]= 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

In[1]:= $CloudVersion
Out[1]= 1.53.0.1 (November 5, 2019)
```

I found a partial list (before my $CloudCredits ran out) of unsupported symbols, meaning they issue the `::cloudf` message:

```
nocloud = {"AudioCapture", "AudioPause", "AudioPlay", "AudioStop", 
   "AudioStream", "AudioStreams", "ConnectSystemModelComponents", 
   "CreateDataSystemModel", "CreateSystemModel", 
   "CurrentNotebookImage", "CurrentScreenImage", "DatabaseConnect", 
   "DatabaseDisconnect", "DatabaseReference", "DeviceClose", 
   "DeviceConfigure", "DeviceExecute", "DeviceExecuteAsynchronous", 
   "DeviceObject", "DeviceOpen", "DeviceRead", "DeviceReadBuffer", 
   "DeviceReadList", "DeviceReadTimeSeries", "Devices", 
   "DeviceStreams", "DeviceWrite", "DeviceWriteBuffer", 
   "DynamicImage", "FindDevices", "FindSystemModelEquilibrium", 
   "FunctionCompile", "FunctionCompileExport", 
   "FunctionCompileExportByteArray", "FunctionCompileExportLibrary", 
   "FunctionCompileExportString", "GestureHandler", "ImageCapture", 
   "InteractiveTradingChart", "NetworkPacketCapture", 
   "NetworkPacketRecording", "PingTime", "RelationalDatabase", 
   "RemoteConnect", "RemoteFile", "RemoteRun", "RemoteRunProcess", 
   "RemoveAudioStream", "SetSystemModel", "SystemDialogInput", 
   "SystemInstall", "SystemModel", "SystemModeler", 
   "SystemModelExamples", "SystemModelLinearize", 
   "SystemModelParametricSimulate", "SystemModelPlot", 
   "SystemModelProgressReporting", "SystemModelReliability", 
   "SystemModels", "SystemModelSimulate", 
   "SystemModelSimulateSensitivity", "SystemModelSimulationData", 
   "SystemProcessData", "SystemProcesses", "DynamicImage", 
   "FunctionCompile", "FunctionCompileExportString", "RemoteConnect", 
   "SystemModel", "SystemModelPlot", "SystemModelSimulate", 
   "SystemModelSimulateSensitivity", "SystemModelSimulationData"};
```

Of course, this doesn't symbols in packages that are missing like FEPrivate, CUDALink, etc. I'd say this question is almost impossible to answer fully, as it differs across platforms and devices. For instance, `CurrentImage[]` works on MacOS in Chrome (if you allow it), but not on the Wolfram Cloud iOS app:

[image]

Comment: You can actually probably check many of these locally by looking for a condition test for `$CloudEvaluation` (or whatever that symbol is called again...). Similarly, you could look for a defined `sym::cloudf` as a first preprocessing step, although that can be bound dynamically.

Comment: @b3m2a1 So I did this by for symbol X running TimeConstrained[CloudEvaluate[X[]],.1] and checking for ::cloudf, but this doesn't work for options, what exactly would you run instead?

Comment: Check `Messages[X]` for `”cloudf"` and check `Keys@Downvalues[X]` for something containing `$CloudEvaluation` to see if it special cases for the cloud. That will give a prefilter then you can write filters on top of that.

Comment: Is there a way to do the cloudevaluate portion without blowing away my cloud credits

Comment: Which I actually did lol

Comment: Your best chance is to evaluate in a cloud notebook itself. Evaluations there don't cost credits (but are time constrained). Also you probably wanted to put the `TimeConstrained` inside the `CloudEvaluate`. You can also make lots of burner accounts by using the `my.email+worker1@blah.bloop` pattern that GMail supports.

Comment: But calling some functions like WebAudioSearch will cost credits

Comment: Then the best choice is to scrape the source itself. You could also evaluate this scrape inside a cloud notebook, that way you wouldn't have to worry about the source being different on the cloud vs. locally.